# Formating USB pen that emulates a CD rom

Tags: usb, virus, formatting

I currently have a USB pen that when inserted on the computer also emulates a CD rom. Even when I try to format it, the CD rom emulation is still there (and with a virus).

How can I completly format the USB pen?

Comment: How are you formatting it now?

Comment: Using windows format (fast format)

Comment: What is the brand and model of the USB pendrive?  Several manufacturers do this, differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a U3 device? U3 devices have special hardware which allows them to emulate a CD-Rom device in a way that allows auto-run to execute properly. You can disable this with the [U3 Launchpad Removal tool](http://mp3support.sandisk.com/downloads/launchpadremoval.exe). [Here](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2550) is a detailed guide with pictures and step-by-step instructions, though if I remember correctly it was pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197)? It's helped me out on a few occasions and works with non-HP devices.

Comment: I'm actually on an HP. Trouble is that I am on Vista/7.

Comment: I've certainly installed and run the app on Windows 7 - give it a try. As for working with non-HP devices, I meant non-HP memory sticks. Good luck.